# Windows phone 7 develop app that opens mail attachment

Tags: windows-phone-7, mime-types, email-attachments

Is it possible? I want that if the attachment is of a particular mime type my app opens it or it will be listed as one of the possible viewer choice... I googled but i found nothing so I'm asking myself if it is possible on windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible... the only way to open a file that has a known mime type is to use a web browser task and to pass a Uri.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot associate MIME-types directly in your application in Windows Phone 7. Your best bet would be to have the user download the file through your application.

Simply saying, you could take a potential workaround of sideloading an application that "fakes" the GUID of an application that is associated on a system level. I wrote about that [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/how-to-trick-windows-phone-os-part-ii--adobe-readers-turn-and-a-general-conclusion). Your problem is, however, the fact that you won't be able to access the file system without proper permissions.